# Extract function from javascript promise (expressjs + neDB)

Tags: javascript, express, promise, nedb

The following code is working and retrieving all users from my neDB-promisses:

> ```
> const getUsers = (res) => {
>   db.find({})
>       .sort({ name: 1 })
>       .exec()
>       .then(
>           (content) => {
>               res.status(200).json(content);
>           },
>           (err) => {
>               res.status(400).json(err);
>           }
>       );
> };
> ```

**What I'm trying to do:** optimize this piece of code in order to avoid future repetitions on CRUD functions, something like this:

> ```
> ...
> .then(successFunctionCall, failureFunctionCall)
> ...
> ```

I thought about creating a separate module called successFunctionCall/failureFunctionCall but I need to call **res** inside it to set the response JSON and status code. Is that a better way to achieve this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can [curry](https://medium.com/better-programming/functional-programming-currying-vs-partial-application-53b8b05c73e3) the functions. When you use them as handlers, pass `res`, and get a new function that waits for the `content` or `err`:

```
const successFunctionCall = res => content => 
  res.status(200).json(content);

const failureFunctionCall = res => err => 
  res.status(400).json(err);

const getUsers = (res) => {
  db.find({})
      .sort({ name: 1 })
      .exec()
      .then(
        successFunctionCall(res),
        failureFunctionCall(res)
      );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid repetitions on CRUD functions, your concerns could be separated a little differently. Below is a basic idea of what I mean.

```js
const usersDb = {} // your users db instance here

const findAllSortedBy = db => (...args) => db.find({}).sort(...args).exec()

const findAllUsersSortedBy = findAllSortedBy(usersDb)

const success = res => content => res.status(200).json(content)

const failure = res => err => res.status(400).json(err)

const getUsers = res => {
  findAllUsersSortedBy({ name: 1 })
    .then(success(res))
    .catch(failure(res))
}
```

here is `getUsers` in context of an express route handler

```js
const getUsers = (req, res) => {
  findAllUsersSortedBy({ name: 1 })
    .then(success(res))
    .catch(failure(res))
}

router.get('/users', getUsers)
```